# Error with Excel after Uploading with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to upload an excel file to my computer using Tkinter and Python.  This is the code I'm using:

```
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")])
    if filename:
       fn = os.path.basename(filename)
       fout=open('...core/files/' + fn, 'wb')
       fout.close()
       print('The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully')
    else:
       print('No file was uploaded')
```

After choosing an excel file and uploading it I always get a success.  But trying to open the uploaded file gives me an Alert that says it can't be opened because the file format or file extension is not valid.  In addition, info on the file says its got 0 bytes.

I have no idea how to fix this..any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You opened the file `fout`, and then closed it without writing anything to it.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh. So how do I write the file?

Comment: I thought the w parameter in the open statement indicated writing the file.

Comment: The "w" does indicate that you intend to write to the file, but it doesn't actually write anything - how would it know what to write?  You presumably need to read the contents of the user-selected file, and then call `fout.write()` with that data.

Comment: I’m still stumped by this since fout.write causes an error.   I guess I need the full code on uploading an excel file.

Comment: I got this working by uploading the excel file to a panda dataframe and then exporting the dataframe to the file I wanted.  Seems like a workaround but it works.

Comment: If you don't change the content of the source file, what you need is just copying the source file to destination folder using `shutil.copy()`.